# Problems with toString(), how to use without calling the object

Tags: java, string, class

sorry if this question doesn't make sense. Also, I'm limiting the code here, and could you also try to do the same as this is for an assignment, and plagarism checkers are annoying :/

So, for an assignment in java, I have to define a method in which it iterates until the simple game is one, printing out the toString() representation between every move. However, I have been unable to get this to work, as there is no object created of the class...

I've tried to call the toString() method without an object before it, however it doesn't print. And I've tried this.toString() as well. Pretty much the code below is a basic mock up of what my method/class look like (not what they actually do)

```
public randClass
{

randClass()
{
Box box = new Box();
Square square = new Square();
Duck duck = new Duck();
}

public void doSomething()
{
toSring(); // also tried this.toString();
do
{
box.postion ++;
square.position = 100 - box.position;
this.toString();
}
while(duck.quack() != true);|
}

public String toString()
{
return box.toString() + " " + square.toString() + ";";
}

}
```

I realise I could just call the box.toString() etc. in place of using a toString() method call, however, the assignment is specifically asking for the randClass object toString() method to be defined.

The toString has also previously worked, however that was with the automated marker creating a randClass object and then calling the method.

Thank you in advance for taking the time to read this, and sorry for being so confusing :(

Comment: Why does it read `toSring()` instead of `toString()` on the line you marked with a comment?

Comment: What does 'without calling the object' mean?

Answer (score 3):

`toString()` in and of itself doesn't print anything, it simply returns a String representation of the Object of which it is a member.

You'll have to pass this String on to a stream of some sort to have it printed to screen or file. Say, to the println method of an `OutputStream`, perhaps like the static one contained in System, possibly named 'out', for instance.

Comment: so, for example using the above,
System.out.println(toString());?

Comment: What an interesting idea, you should try that, but you didn't hear it from me.

Comment: Thank you :)
Just realised how noobish this was :/ 
Sorry for the trouble :)

Comment: No trouble, glad I could help